# C++ 2D Char array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

please help me to solve it.....
Write a simple telephone directory program; contain two dimensional arrays in which you have hard code names and telephone number. Then declare a simple character array. You have to prompt user to enter any name, which you want to search. This name should be store in this character array, then search this name from the two dimensional array. If number is found against entered name then program should display the number against this name, and if not found then program should display the message that name is not registered.

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done. Don't ask us to write code for you. Show us your code.

Comment: still i did this i need next step how to do it.............#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
main()
{
 int i;
 char names[5][7]= {"Ali","Umar","Naveed", "Raheel","Raja"};
 char numbers[5][13]= {"5302-4578961","0301-2222222","042-3654789","0340-0598569","0307-5308821"};
 char finder[7];
 cout<<"enter a name to find number"<<endl;
 cin>>finder;
  
    
    
   }

Comment: Good, edit that into the question body using the code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints to help you get started:

- C++ arrays only allow a single type, so what datatype allows you to store text such as a name and telephone number?
- How might you search an array? Perhaps you could check (iterate) each element for the desired value
- User input can be achieved with `cin` or `getline()`
- You can write to the console with `cout` or `printf`
- for loops can be used to loop a specific number of times, such as the **amount of elements in an array**
- Array elements can be accessed using `arrayname[index][index]`, indexes start at 0, so the first element is not index of 1, but index of 0.
- An example 2D array looks like this:
  .

`int array[2][2] { //specify the datatype, and the amount of elements

                          //also specify the amount in each nested array
            {34, 42}      //first nested array, 2 elements, 42 could be accessed using
                          // array[0][1]
            {2, 432}      //second nested array, 2 elements 2 could be accessed using 
                          //array[1][0]
        }`

**EDIT:**
Ok, a good start, but here are a couple key issues with the code you posted.

- `main()` needs a return type specified, specifically it is `int main()`, also add a return statement at the end of the function such as `return 1`
- The names and numbers should be in the same array, see the tip I wrote above
- To proceed, fix the arrays and add `cin` to get user input.

Comment: How i do or edit it i m new on this website and i have only one more day to submit assignment.

Comment: Also, I have practically given you the code, read the hints and figure it out. I'm not doing the assignment for you.